# Django urlpatterns: meaning of regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django

I am following Django tutorial from [django website.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial03/)

There I see a regular expression like:

```
(regular expression, **Python callback function [, optional dictionary]**)
```

What I could understand is first element of the tuple is a regular expression. But I am struggling to understand part in bold in context of regular expressions and django as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the regular expression is a string. The callback function is a function to be called when the regex is matched, with the arguments given in the optional dictionary as a supplement to those parsed from the URL via the regex.

Comment: oh crap..I am so dumb.. I was confused by square brackets [, something]... I knew that "square brackets" is syntax for optional arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the second argument is the callback to be used when a regex match is found. This callback can be a string or a callable object. The string itself must get evaluated to a callable object. The next element is a dictionary which can be optionally passed to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

> There I see a regular expression like:
>
> What I could understand is the regular expression is a tuple.

No. That is not a regular expression. It is a tuple. Regular expressions are strings. Tuples are completely different things. They are groupings of related pieces of information. A regular expression cannot be a tuple, because it is a string.

The `urlpatterns` variable contains a sequence of tuples. Each tuple contains either two or three items. In each tuple, the first item is a regular expression. The second item of each tuple is a function. The third item, if present, is a dictionary.